# How to use REST API in MYSQL (Request and Response)

Tags: mysql, oracle, rest, soap, xmlhttprequest

Just like in Oracle where we can use the `UTL_HTTP`/SOAP API for request and response, we are looking for a REST API call in MYSQL.

1. Is there any alternative for `UTL_HTTP` in MYSQL?
2. Also, need an example for REST API call in MYSQL.

Comment: But a database is not meant to do stuff like that.

Comment: @luuk - *"a database is not meant to do stuff like that."* Well that depends on what one thinks a database is meant to do. I agree a lot of people think a database should just be a passive receptacle for data, but there are other paradigms.